# How to create an outlook search folder in a pst-archive by means of VBA which scans all folders contained in this archive?

Tags: vba, search, outlook, pst

**Starting situation:**

Outlook 2016 is connected to the mailbox `"Name@Domain"` and a local `"Archive"`. The mailbox uses IMAP/SMTP and a local OST-file. `"Archive"` is a local PST-file.

**Test job:**

Display all elements contained in the mailbox or archive in a search folder named `"TEST"` which is created using VBA:

```
Public FlagAdvancedSearchComplete As Boolean

Private Sub Application_AdvancedSearchComplete (ByVal SearchObject As Search)
    FlagAdvancedSearchComplete = True
End Sub

Sub CreateSearchFolder_TEST()

    Dim MyScope  As String
    Dim MySearch As Search

    MyScope = "'\\Name@Domain'"
   'MyScope = "'\\Archive'"

    Set MySearch = Application.AdvancedSearch _
    (Scope:=MyScope, Filter:="", SearchSubFolders:=True, Tag:="MySearchFolder")

    Do While FlagAdvancedSearchComplete = False
        DoEvents
    Loop  

    MySearch.Save ("TEST")

End Sub
```

**Findings:**

The VBA-code creates the desired search folder `"TEST"` in `"Name@Domain“` as expected. However, if  `MyScope = "'\\Archive'"` is activated instead of `'MyScope = "'\\Name@Domain‘"` execution stops at the line `MySearch.Save ("TEST")` with the following error message:

```
Run time error -2147221241 (80040107):
Procedure could not be executed. Object not found.
```

**What needs to be changed in the code in order to make it work with all mailboxes and archives?**

Comment: Have you tried to create a search folder in the archive store manually? Do you get any errors in that case?

Comment: Yes, manual creation works perfectly. Unfortunately, there are hundreds of archives where to create search folders ...

Comment: Is there any search folder with the same name?

Comment: No, there are no search folders with the same name, neither in the mailbox nor in the archive. Usually, there's no search folder at all.

Comment: Apparently not with the Outlook Object Model  https://stackoverflow.com/a/67628899/1571407. "In OOM, you can enumerate existing search folders using Store.GetSearchFolders(), but you cannot create search folders on the per-store basis."

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Unfortunately, I did not take note of it earlier. However, I did not expect any more answer. Nevertheless I will try.