# Change the Outlook account where to create a searchfolder with advancedsearch method and search object save method

Tags: vba, outlook

I am using the Save method of the Search object that is returned by the advancedSearch method to create a Search Folder.

As I have multiple accounts in my Outlook, the search folder is always created under the same account (Default ?).
Do you know if it is possible to change the account where I want the search folder to be created ?

Here is the code I am using that I found on the official MS documentation

```
Public blnSearchComp As Boolean 
 
Private Sub Application_AdvancedSearchComplete(ByVal SearchObject As Search) 
 MsgBox "The AdvancedSearchComplete Event fired" 
 blnSearchComp = True  
End Sub 
 
Sub TestAdvancedSearchComplete() 
 Dim sch As Outlook.Search 
 Dim rsts As Outlook.Results 
 Dim i As Integer 

 blnSearchComp = False 
 
 Const strF As String = "urn:schemas:mailheader:subject = 'Test'" 
 Const strS As String = "Inbox" 
 
 Set sch = Application.AdvancedSearch(strS, strF) 
 
 While blnSearchComp = False 
   DoEvents 
 Wend 
 
 sch.Save("Subject Test") 
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In OOM, you can enumerate existing search folders using `Store.GetSearchFolders()`, but you cannot create search folders on the per-store basis.

If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, you can use [RDOFolder.Folders.AddSearchFolder](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOSearchFolder.htm) to create a search folder anywhere and set its properties explicitly (the folder may or may not be visible to the user). You can also use [RDOStore.Searches.AddCustom](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosearches.htm) to create a search visible to the end-user under the "Searches" node in the folder tree view.

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set Store = Session.Stores.DefaultStore 'can be any other store
set Searches = Store.Searches
strSQL = " Subject LIKE '%Test%'"
Dim excludedFolders(0)
excludedFolders(0) = olFolderJunk
set NewSearch = Searches.AddCustom("Test", strSQL, Store.IPMRootFolder, true, excludedFolders)
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry,

Thanks for your feedback. 
I am afraid that I wont be able to use Redemption as I understand it requires a new DLL installation and, if my understanding is correct, the company policy where i work will prevent me to add this.
Big thank you anyway for your clarification about the unabilty to create search folders on the per-store basis. It is already a big help and it will make me reviewing my approach and find an alternative path.
Best regards,
Attilio